# I want to have a d3 v4 sunburst chart with uniform thin rings

Tags: d3.js, ember.js

[Please find the image attached here .I want the sunburst chart to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pdHw.png) I am using the example at
http://bl.ocks.org/maybelinot/5552606564ef37b5de7e47ed2b7dc099

Could anyone help me with modifying this code to get uniform thin rings with a huge hollow centre?

Answer (score 0):

d3 arc implementation is quite easy. It's all about four parameters

- startAngle
- endAngle
- innerRadius
- outerRadius

  `var arc = d3.arc()
  .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x0))); })
  .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x1))); })
  .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y0)); })
  .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y1)); });`

and also the **radius** of the arc.
Do some changes in the above mentioned params that will change the arc

Comment: I tried various combination in the arc..only then i posted ! I have posted a image,i want the sunburst chart to be rendered like that